# Generate multiple output xml files on basis of Data in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

i have written down a simple apache camel route which transforms csv to xml file. However, i want to generate multiple xml on basis of CompanyName i-e same companyname employees in one file. My route is as follow

```
            public void configure() throws Exception
            {
                from("file:C:\\Users\\Desktop?fileName=data.csv")
                        .process(new MyTransform())
                        .to("file:C:\\Users\\Desktop?fileName=emp.xml");
            }
        });
```

MyTransform class is

```
public class MyTransform implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String myString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String[] lineSeparator = myString.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("<Company>");
        for (String lineData : lineSeparator)
        {
            String [] commaSeparator=lineData.split(",");
            sb.append("<CompanyName>"+commaSeparator[0].toString()+"</CompanyName>");
            sb.append("<Name>"+commaSeparator[1].toString()+"</Name>");
            sb.append("<Salary>"+commaSeparator[2].toString()+"</Salary>");
            sb.append("</Employee>");
        }
        sb.append("</Employees>");
        System.out.println("MyProcessor complete");
        exchange.getIn().setBody(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

I am completely new to apache camel. Kindly guide me where should i head to achieve my output.

Comment: You need to setup an aggregator using the company name as a correlation id.

Comment: but as far i have studied aggregator allows to combine different input to single input. I want the opposite

Comment: If there is only a single csv file, what you have to do is implement a splitter, then aggregate on the company name as the correlation id. The correlation id will ensure that multiple files with the same company name are created.

Comment: i have been trying with splitter but due to my less knowledge i am getting error "route not found". Can you please elaborate a bit more